# Android Wear Data Transmission: Messages, WearableListener or Channel?

Tags: wear-os

My goal is to constantly send the data of the watch's accelerometer to the handheld.

Grabbing the sensor data is fairly easy, but I'm a little clueless about the best way to get them as a constant stream to the handheld. Do I use the MessageApi? Wouldn't be channels the best pick?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

DataAPI sounds perfect sense to me in this case, through its method DataChanged you can watch any change in the streaming, because the stream from watch's accelerometer will be changing constantly, I suppose. This api must be implemented in both activities (wear and handheld).